# Shacl sh:qualifiedValueShape expression abbreviation

Tags: shacl

Let say that i am trying to express that a **Binding** must have *exactly 1* **partner** that is a **FunctionalClass** and *exactly 1* **partner** that is **Protein**.

I wonder if this is enough

```
resnet:Binding
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
  rdfs:label "Binding" ;
  rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ;
  sh:property [
      sh:path resnet:partner ;
      sh:NodeKind sh:IRI ;
      sh:qualifiedMaxCount 1 ;
      sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
      sh:qualifiedValueShape [
          sh:class resnet:FunctionalClass ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
  sh:property [
      sh:path resnet:partner ;
      sh:NodeKind sh:IRI ;
      sh:qualifiedMaxCount 1 ;
      sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
      sh:qualifiedValueShape [
          sh:class resnet:Protein ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
.
```

Or do i need the full ceremony

```
resnet:Binding
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
  rdfs:label "Binding" ;
  rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ;
  sh:property [
      sh:path resnet:partner ;
      sh:minCount 2 ;
      sh:maxCount 2 ;
    ] ;
  sh:property [
      sh:path resnet:partner ;
      sh:qualifiedMaxCount 1 ;
      sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
      sh:qualifiedValueShape [
          sh:class resnet:FunctionalClass ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
  sh:property [
      sh:path resnet:partner ;
      sh:qualifiedMaxCount 1 ;
      sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
      sh:qualifiedValueShape [
          sh:class resnet:Protein ;
        ] ;
    ] ;
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need the second for the case where some partner is both FunctionalClass and a Protein, i.e. you may only have one value and still fulfill the first shape.

Alternatively, this looks like a case for sh:qualifiedValueShapesDisjoint